# In Java despite being configured as keep alive, HTTPS creates multiple client ports

Tags: java, http, https, httpclient, keep-alive

A chunked encoded response is provided by a simple web application I have deployed. Just to be sure that the keep-alive is honored, I call this URL connection twice in a loop.

It is clear that the client port changes with each iteration when I capture the tcp packets and check them.
Only during https calls does this happen, whereas during http calls it always reuses the client port.

I call this method in a loop, and s_provider takes the value
https://hostname:8443/servlet/testchunk or
http://hostname:8080/servlet/testchunk

```
private static Serializable invoke() {
    HttpConnCxt httpcontext = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
      httpcontext = openConnection(new URL(s_provider));
      httpcontext.out.flush();
      httpcontext.out.close();
      httpcontext.in = new ObjectInputStream(httpcontext.uc.getInputStream());

      try {
        result = (String)httpcontext.in.readObject();
        Integer i = (Integer)httpcontext.in.readObject();
        Long l1 = (Long)httpcontext.in.readObject();
      } catch (java.io.EOFException eofEx) {
        eofEx.printStackTrace();
      }
      return result;
    } catch (Exception x) {
      x.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if (httpcontext != null && httpcontext.in != null)
          httpcontext.in.close();
      } catch (Exception x) {}
    }
    return result;
  }
```

According to the TCP dump captured during https iteration-1:
The client port is 54888, and the server port is 8443

In iteration-2:
The client port used is 54889, and the server port remains 8443.

Is there a reason why https does not reuse the client port?

## Edited: Method openConnection(..)

```
private static HttpConnCxt openConnection(URL mUrl) throws Exception {
    HttpConnCxt httpConnCxt = new HttpConnCxt(null, null, null);
    try {
      httpConnCxt.uc = mUrl.openConnection();
      configureConnection(httpConnCxt.uc);
      httpConnCxt.uc.setDoInput(true);
      httpConnCxt.uc.setDoOutput(true);
      httpConnCxt.uc.setUseCaches(false);
      httpConnCxt.uc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
      httpConnCxt.uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
      httpConnCxt.out = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(httpConnCxt.uc.getOutputStream());
      return httpConnCxt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
```

With http, the same code works fine, but with https, the client port changes.

Comment: Looks like you explicitly close connection in your code.

Comment: You probably need to show us `openConnection` code.

Comment: @talex : I have edited my question to add the openConnectionMethod()
With http, the same code works fine, but with https, the client port changes.

Comment: When a client creates a secured connection(https) but is unable to receive the final chunk, it treats the initial port it opened as in-progress or busy and opens a new one to proceed with the next request. 

In my case, that is what is happening. In order to validate it, I enabled the Java debugging feature "javax.net.debug" in Java.

Comment: I used two different client libraries weblogic client libs and default java package libs, application was deployed on Weblogic. 

According to the client logs, I could see that the final chunk was read when the weblogic client libraries were used.

However, I was unable to see the final chunk when using the default Java packages.

Comment: Have you tried draining the HttpURLConnection input stream before closing it?